# How to Subscribe to some event of component using a Directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular12

This is my components Pagination.

```
<pagination
  [boundaryLinks]="true"
  [(ngModel)]="currentPage"
  [totalItems]="100"
  previousText="&lsaquo;"
  nextText="&rsaquo;"
  firstText="&laquo;"
  lastText="&raquo;"
  (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)"
  [maxSize]="5"
  my-pagination="tableTwo"
></pagination>
```

And this is my Directive

```
@Directive ({
  selector: "pagination[my-pagination]"
})

export class MyPagination {
  constructor( private el: ElementRef){
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('my-pagination'))
  }
  ngOnInit(){
  }
}
```

Now after getting the element in my Directive i want to use the value in my-pagination which for reference is table name(tableTwo) and scroll to the Header of the table. But I am not getting how can i know in my directive when the page has changed and perform the functionality. Need some help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass not the "table name" else the elementRef of the table. For this you can use a template reference variable

But Angular not allow the `-` in names so you should change first a by some like,e.g. tableRef

Then just use an input in your directive

```
@Input() tableRef:any
```

Your main.component becomes like

```
<table #tableHead">
...
</table>

<pagination
  ...
  [tableRef]="tableHead"
></pagination>
```

and you use like

```
@Directive ({
  selector: "pagination[my-pagination]"
})
export class MyPagination implement AfterViewInit {

  @Input() tableRef:any

  constructor(){
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(){
     if (this.tableRef)
        this.tableRef.scrollIntoView()
  }
}
```

NOTE: You if you don't expect change the variable you can use [@attribute](https://angular.io/api/core/Attribute)

```
@Directive ({
  selector: "pagination[my-pagination]"
})
export class MyPagination implement AfterViewInit {

  constructor(@Optional()@Attribute('tableRef') private tableRef: any) {

  ngAfterViewInit(){
     if (this.tableRef)
        this.tableRef.scrollIntoView()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works. But I am thinking of a usecase where there are multiple pagination and multiple tables are there. It wont work in that case right?

Comment: if the tables are in a loop and the component.pagination is inside the loop you have no problem (the "scope" makes that the template reference variable match). If are tables standalone, just use diferent template reference variables